# How to build field range index based on element name and having specified parent

Tags: xml, marklogic

Here is a sample `XML` which I have in the database:

```
<Device>
    <Name>device1</Name>
    <Sensors>
        <Sensor>
            <Name>sensor1</Name>
        </Sensor>
        <Sensor>
            <Name>sensor2</Name>
        </Sensor>
</Device>
```

I want to build `Field Range Index` for Name element with Device parent element, but not for Name elements from Sensor. Based on field configuration rules, I cannot just add Name element to the field and exclude Sensors element. Is there any solution in MarkLogic 5? According to the requirements for my app, I cannot transform documents and change element names.

Comment: Seems an unusual way to specify a requirement.  Suspect you can do what you want wrt reading the data out of the database in that specific serialized XML format, but you will need a different (better) model inside the database (same as you might want a different table structure in an rdbms)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is "No". But there are of course ways forward.

If you're amenable to adding an attribute (but leaving the element name unchanged), you could constrain the field by that, e.g.:

```
<Device>
  <Name _field="DeviceName">device1</Name>
  ...
</Device>
```

The attribute/value pair can be anything you want; you just have to tell the field definition, what it is. A good practice might be to `namespace-qualify` the attribute, so it's clearly an annotation from a different vocabulary, e.g.:

```
<Device xmlns:field="http://example.com/field-annotations">
  <Name field:name="DeviceName">device1</Name>
  ...
</Device>
```

Range indexes can currently only be tied to element values, attribute values, and field values. Fields let you abstract a little bit from the underlying structure, but not as much as a more generic mechanism would.

Another technique sometimes employed (though I haven't personally tried this) is to use two databases, one that's slightly more "logical" (e.g., a standard format, unchanged) and one that's more `database-optimized`.

Whatever approach you decide, a little more work is necessary.

If I were you, I'd probably write an `XSLT` transform which could be applied on input, and another simple one for returning the original unannotated version if I ever need it.

annotate.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:field="http://example.com/field-annotations">

  <xsl:import href="copy.xsl"/>

  <!-- Annotate Device/Name as a field -->
  <xsl:template mode="add-att" match="Device/Name">
    <xsl:attribute name="field:name" select="'DeviceName'"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

cleanup.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:field="http://example.com/field-annotations">

  <xsl:import href="copy.xsl"/>

  <!-- Delete all field:* attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="@field:*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

copy.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Don't add any attributes by default -->
  <xsl:template mode="add-att" match="*"/>

  <!-- recursively copy elements -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-att" select="."/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- copy attributes and child nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can apply `annotate.xsl` using `xdmp:xslt-invoke()` in your application code for inserting documents into the database. Or you can configure `annotate.xsl` as a transformer in an Information Studio flow.

When you want to retrieve the pristine doc, just call:

```
xdmp:xslt-invoke("cleanup.xsl", doc("my-doc.xml"))
```

But for most cases in regular application code, you don't need to clean up the document. Since, the presence of an extra attribute will rarely have any effect there.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose adding attribute from different namespace is a good solution for my case.

Answer (score 1):

As of Marklogic 6, this is exactly the problem that path range indexes are designed to solve:

http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/path-range-indexes